# Django REST Framework throttling / authorization with React or other front-end JS library

Tags: json, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Django REST framework has a throttling feature
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Understand that with throttling can limit unauthorized users browsing my app but endpoints of REST are publicly visible for example:

https://exampledomain.com/api/v2/courses/ - this would be example endpoint

Do I setup Django REST with token or any other authorization and then save that token in env variables (config variables) that app can use that and be authorized or what is the proper way to handle that - can you point me to right direction somehow - what I am trying to accomplish is that nobody can take the endpoints and try to post things agains them, only web application is allowed to do that and meaning not only POST but as GET and other requests.

Comment: If you don't want to allow ***unauthorized users***, use [**`IsAuthenticated`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) permission policy rather than throttling policy

Comment: @JPG Maybe I have not explained it properly - the website has no login or anything people would be browsing the site as it is - so that's why all people are unauthorized - since the site is using API to feed React or any JS library VUE or anything else - I do not want some people go into source of HTML and JS and use the endpoints how they want - I want only the website to be authorized to use the API not other 3rd party applications. Like API would be restricted that way that it knows it is being accessed by the site on the server and not by someone else outside the server.....